# How to set Conditional Row Number by ordinal string values in sub-column from the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

If query returns the table:

| col | sub_col |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | A |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| B | A |
| B | B |
| B | B |
| B | C |
| B | A |
| B | B |
| B | B |
| B | C |

Output should be like:

| col | sub_col | order_by_sub_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 0 |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | C | 2 |
| A | A | 0 |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | C | 2 |
| B | A | 0 |
| B | B | 1 |
| B | B | 2 |
| B | C | 3 |
| B | A | 0 |
| B | B | 1 |
| B | B | 2 |
| B | C | 3 |

Comment: so where is the query?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: @odaiwa 
- question: How to set Conditional Row Number by ordinal string values in sub-column from the table?
- query is first table as input, I need output of second table with new third column(order_by_sub_col)